# Ionic angular dynamic grid display of a json

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

This is how I get my data back from the backend service:

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {date: "2021-05-17", time: "+4:56"}
1: {date: "2021-05-18", time: "+5:34"}
```

How would i dynamically create an ionic grid for the needed size of the retrieved data in json format?

In this case I want the grid to have 2 rows and 2 columns and in each row, there would be date in the first column and time in the second one.

I saw a ngFor* operator, but I don't know how to use it on the retrieved data that is stored in a model called "retrievedData". I can easily access data with the retrievedData[0][0] in typescript file (where the data is retrieved) and get the result "2021-05-17", but I don't know how to do it dynamically in the html file, where i should forloop through the retrievedData and display it as I described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`html code`

```
<ion-row *ngFor="let item of retrievedData" >
        <ion-col size="6">{{item?.date}}</ion-col>
        <ion-col size="6">{{item?.time}}</ion-col>
      </ion-row>
```

`ts code`

```
public retrievedData = [
    { date: "2021-05-17", time: "+4:56" },
    { date: "2021-05-18", time: "+5:34" }
  ]
```

Comment: Ty, i also had to create an empty public retreivedData = [] in .ts and then set this.retreivedData = retreivedDatam that was obtained from query.